What happened to the slot-machine-like select menu on iOS WEBKIT, that appeared at the bottom, with haptic feedback etc
Does anyone know what happened to the slot-machine-like select menu on iOS WEBKIT, used to appear at the bottom, had haptic feedback etc

While now is

I couldn't find much information for when was it updated or any docs related stuff. I clearly remember it appearing on Web Safari / Chrome
